# payfort Invalid extra parameters

Tags: payfort

I am using the payfort Merchant page.

When I am making a token the request succeeds but when I tried to make a purchase I got  " Invalid extra parameters" code 00027

This the request of TOKENIZATION

Request Log

```
card_security_code  ***
card_number 523761******2016
service_command TOKENIZATION
signature   $signature
merchant_identifier ZDFytEce
merchant_reference  $merchant_ref
access_code $access_code
expiry_date ***
return_url  TOKEN_RETUEN_URL
language    en
```

Response Log

```
response_code   18000
card_number 
signature   i have removed signature
merchant_identifier 
expiry_date ***
access_code 
language    en
response_message    Success
service_command TOKENIZATION
merchant_reference   i have removed it 
token_name  E61B3D3066C611EAB1270AC1838006C8
return_url   i have removed it 
status  18
card_bin     i have removed it
```

and this is the PURCHASE Request which fails

```
Request Log
amount  10000
signature   $signature
merchant_identifier $merhcanct
access_code $accees_code
customer_ip ::1
language    en
command PURCHASE
merchant_reference  $merchant_ref
customer_email  ahmed@email.com
token_name  1551899mwGbPzTwdbP3JAX9eCmENqu
return_url  PRUCHASE_RETURN
currency    EGP
customer_name   Ahmed
```

Response Log

```
amount  10000
response_code   00027
signature   i have removed it 
merchant_identifier i have removed it
access_code i have removed it
customer_ip ::1
language    en
command PURCHASE
response_message    Invalid extra parameters   // error here
merchant_reference  11125-1584279525
customer_email  ahmed@email.com
currency    EGP
customer_name   Ahmed 
status  00
```

Comment: sorry for invalid Question format this is first time to post a question here

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have fixed your formatting, please try to use the post preview to ensure it looks right before posting.

Comment: OKay , thanks a lot :)

Comment: Did you by any chance figure it out??
I am having the same exact problem

Comment: @IMAK 
    yeah Thanks to God it works now, it just was that curl was used to send the request and getting back the response, but it was disabled in my  php.ini so after adding the curl extension it worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now, it just was that curl was used to send the request and getting back the response, but it was disabled in my `php.ini`, so after adding the curl extension it worked out.