# "Invalid extra parameters : token_name" PAYFORT INTEGRATION

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, payfort

I am using Merchant Page 2.0 documentation as it was told by the payfort in the email. I am integrating payfort with nodejs. I am sending all the required parameters in the request body. the TOKENIZATION request was successful but the PURCHASE request is not. I am getting the respose "Invalid extra parameters : token_name". If you look at the documentation of the merchant page 2.0, you will find that token_name is a mandatory parameter.?
Note: the problem is similar to [payfort Invalid extra parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694908/payfort-invalid-extra-parameters). but this is solution for Php, and i need a solution for nodejs.
below is my request

```
 new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      await axios
        .post(
          "https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi",
          {
            command: "PURCHASE",
            access_code: "some",
            merchant_identifier: "some",
            merchant_reference: "some",
            amount: 50000,
            currency: "AED",
            language: "en",
            customer_email: customer_email,
            customer_ip: "some ip address",
            token_name: 'somethoken',
            signature: newSignature,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "content-type": "application/json",
            },
            // params: {

            // },
          }
        ).then((response)=>{

})
```

Plase responde as soon as possible as we are on a time frame
Thanks in advance for your time and considration.

Comment: i am trying to use payfort with ionic 3 , i tried redirection mode first with inappbrowser with it. But my problem is i receive fortId only after payment success , i didnt get all other params like succes status. Can you please help me how to use payfort with ionic 3 in merchent page 2 mode? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if it will help anyone but it was a stupid mistake. I was using tokanization endpoint for payment as well thats why it was occurring, once it was corrected, everything worked fine. I also got stuck at another  stage where response was returning invalid token. After arranging a call with the payfort people, found out that the token is only valid for 8-10 minutes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).